# What material should I use to store molten metal?

Tags: metallurgy, corrosion, ceramics

I'm performing an experiment based on slag corrosion behavior of the refractory material. I need to store molten metal at $\approx$ 1600-1700 K for that.

Specifically, I'm working on slag corrosion and penetration behaviour of refractory (MgO-MgAl2O4). I'm going to use immersion method, so in this method "Cylindrical or square pillar shaped samples are held in the corrosive liquid(slag) in a furnace. Immersion time, temperature and atmosphere can be varied" So, for storing slag+molten metal, I need to use a crucible.

Please suggest what would be the best choice of material for crucible.
What is a crucible material?

Comment: What have you found so far? What gets used in foundries?

Comment: Have you looked at any table of element melting points (and/or alloys)?

Comment: Refractory lined steel crucible.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a silicon carbide crucible.  The melting point is like 3000k which should serve your purposes.  Also as I recall, it is inert to most molten metals.

You say you are testing slag with molten metal.  What is the metal?  Do you know what the slag is composed of?

Comment: mostly molten steel
slag CaO-Al2O3-SiO2
basicity approx 1.7-1.8

Comment: If you check literature , I think you will find small amount of " bad actors" like Fl and Zn cause most of the refractory deterioration.  Not my area, but I have read that "acid" slag or "basic" slag is important. Look at " Making and Shaping of Steel" by USSteel.